# How can run db2look command for newly created user

Tags: cmd, db2, ddl

I am working on db2 to get ddl of objects.

I have create new user with hunny name in windows 10.

The command which i have executed to get ddl of objects in db2 is :-

```
db2look  -i hunny -w hunny -z admin -d sample -server 192.168.1.64 -dp -td : -e -x -o C:\test\db_new.sql
```

When i executed that command using cmd then i got following error .

```
 Error Message =
SQL0551N  The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have
the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.
Authorization ID: "HUNNY".  Operation: "EXECUTE". Object:
"NULLID.DB2L2O1W".  SQLSTATE=42501


SQLCA
Size    = 136
SQLCODE = -551
Tokens  = HUNNY _ EXECUTE _ NULLID.DB2L2O1W
RDS fn  = SQLRA13E
RC      = 0x801A006D = -2145779603
Reason  = 0x0000 = 0
Reason2 = 0x0000 = 0
Line #  = -20
Warning flags =
```

Please suggest what kind of privileges I should give to user to execute db2look command.

Answer (score 0):

As a minimum, [db2look](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html) requires `SELECT` on the catalog tables (by default it is available to `PUBLIC` - should be ok).

The error is likely caused by the binding of packages. If the user executing db2look has SYSADM and DBADM, everything is ok. But in this case not all privileges to bind the packages for db2look are present. I recommend taking a look at [this blog article](http://db2commerce.com/2015/06/09/a-couple-of-db2look-problems/) that explains how to work around it.